# Ruby regex fails when there is a parenthesis in the pattern and Regex.escape does not work

Tags: regex, ruby

This is almost embarrassing: I've used ruby regular expressions for years, but cannot get this simple example to work.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

# 15 March 2023

t1 = "Acanthochelys macrocephala (Rhodin, Mittermeier, and McMorris 1984)"

t2 = "Acanthochelys macrocephala (Rhodin, Mittermeier,"

if t1 =~ /#{t2}/
    puts "got a match!"
    puts "match = #{$~}"
    puts
end
```

When this is run, we get:

./try.2.rb:21:in `': end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /Acanthochelys macrocephala (Rhodin, Mittermeier,/ (RegexpError)

If we try to escape the strings by adding to the above:

```
x1 = Regexp.escape(t1)

puts x1

x2 = Regexp.escape(t2)

puts x2

if x1 =~ /#{x2}/
    puts "finally got a match!"
    puts $~
else
    puts "no match!"
end
```

we get:

```
Acanthochelys\ macrocephala\ \(Rhodin,\ Mittermeier,\ and\ McMorris\ 1984\)
Acanthochelys\ macrocephala\ \(Rhodin,\ Mittermeier
no match!,
```

with no match instead of getting a simple regex match.

Taking out the parentheses by hand makes this code work, but doesn't solve the problem I have as I'm searching a ~33,500 line file with hundreds of parentheses.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't you want `if t1 =~ /#{x2}/`? i.e. why escape the string you're *not* using in a regex?

Comment: `t1.match?(Regexp.escape(t2)) #=> true`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to escape the string that you're using for the regex. If you escape both strings then you'll add backslashes to the non-regex string and those will break your matching.

So you want something more like this:

```
t1 = "Acanthochelys macrocephala (Rhodin, Mittermeier, and McMorris 1984)"
t2 = "Acanthochelys macrocephala (Rhodin, Mittermeier,"
if t1 =~ /#{Regexp.escape(t2)}/
  puts "got a match!"
  puts "match = #{$~}"
end
```

Comment: This works! Not escaping the string while escaping the regex solves the problem. I did not know that. Thanks!